# Error while restoring db from Enterprise to BI edition of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, cdc

Every day we restore backups from production on 3 different servers. Same process has been used for months and it always works. Recently we decided to start restoring backups from production server on the 4th server meant for BI. We are however unable to do it as database restores well at first and once the restore finishes database goes into "Suspect" mode and the following message is displayed:

> Msg 3908, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Could not run BEGIN TRANSACTION in database 'DatabaseName' because the database is in emergency mode or is damaged and must be restarted.
>
> Msg 3314, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
>   During undoing of a logged operation in database 'DatabaseName', an error occurred at log record ID (205933:123232:2). Typically, the specific failure is logged previously as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database or file from a backup, or repair the database.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> Msg 934, Level 21, State 1, Line 3
>   SQL Server cannot load database 'DatabaseName' because Change Data Capture is enabled. The currently installed edition of SQL Server does not support Change Data Capture. Either disable Change Data Capture in the database by using a supported edition of SQL Server, or upgrade the instance to one that supports Change Data Capture.
>
> Msg 933, Level 21, State 1, Line 3
>   Database 'DatabaseName' cannot be started because some of the database functionality is not available in the current edition of SQL Server.
>
> Msg 3314, Level 21, State 5, Line 3
>   During undoing of a logged operation in database 'DatabaseName', an error occurred at log record ID (205933:123232:1). Typically, the specific failure is logged previously as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database or file from a backup, or repair the database.

From the error message it looks like we have the problem with one of the log entries, but if this is the case why are we able to restore same backups on different servers?

Our production server from where the backups are coming runs SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition and has CDC enabled on 4 tables.

Our BI server on which I am trying to restore the backup runs SQL Server BI edition.

Is there any way to bypass this without disabling cdc? Unfortunately we are not allowed to disable this particular feature. I did my reading, but I was unable to find anything helpful.

The only way around that I see is to restore backup on another server, disable cdc and then back up new database and transfer backup to BI server. It more more complicated and hence more likely to break than direct backup transfer. If you see any better way please let me know. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think this question is better asked on dba.stackexchange.com. This is a site similar to StackOverflow, but that deals solely with database administration

Comment: Thank you TT. Do you happen to know how I can move my question?

Comment: I've flagged the question to be moved to that site. However the community needs to agree for that to happen. If it isn't moved, you are free to create an account on dba.stackexchange.com. That site is part of the same network, you can create an account with the same credentials as on StackOverflow. HTH.

Comment: Thank you. i appreciate your help